# Open url in browser and fill asp.net popup with values from wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Wpf application and I want to open url (asp page) and fill popup with values (login, password). How can I do it?

Now I open url with Process.Start:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(url);
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

But I can't find out a way to fill popup..

I find way to use webControl... but I need to open url in browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation is to think whether a mechanism like this is really necessary because it deals with a lot of sensitive Information. If you can avoid it, I'd recommend not to use at least the password.
Can you make changes to the ASP-page? Then you can add some request parameters that the ASP application fills into the fields, you could do that. 

However, in this specific scenario I strongly recommend **NOT** to fill the username and password directly in the URL because it can be read easily along the path. If the application runs in a completely safe, controlled area, one can argue about the username, but I would not recommend it.
What you could do is to create some kind of token mechanism, so that you do not transmit sensitive data:

1. WPF application creates token, e.g. in database. It is important that the token is random and cannot be guessed, maybe a GUID. Also it should be valid only for a short period of time. Also the WPF application stores the necessary login Information in the database.
2. WPF application opens the browser with an URL like `https://srv?token=<random token>`.
3. ASP application receives token through request Parameter, checks whether it is still valid and signs user in using the Information that is stored along with the token. It deletes the entry in the database immediately so that the token cannot be reused.

This approach requires you to be able to make changes to both the WPF application and also the ASP application.
And as said above, if you can avoid it, it is preferrable to have the user enter his or her credentials manually.

Comment: Markus, thank you for answer!
I think it is good idea using db, but I can't change that page..

Comment: Do you think using webcontrol is better?

Comment: Let's rethink this from a security Point of view. My first concern is why and how you can access the passwords in clear text (or in a form that you can decrypt to clear text). This is a huge security threat. If someone manages to access your database he or she is capable of using the accounts of all your users. I'd avoid this under any circumstance. So it would be best to rethink this requirement and have the users enter their credentials manually. Of course this takes time but is by far better than having to communicate to your users that their credentials have been stolen.

Comment: Now to the WebControl: In this approach, at least you do not send the passwords over the Network or have to implement a token mechanism that requires a lot of costly changes. However, if you use the WebControl heavily, there are reports of memory leaks that can occure under certain circumstances and so on. Also not a "favorite" approach, but if you can implement it in a stable way maybe acceptable if you cannot change the requirements and the web application.

Comment: Thank you, Markus. I will think about it.

Comment: Let's for a minute forgot about security. How can I fill popup window? Is there any class for it?

Comment: By popup window, do you mean a separate browser window that you created using Process.Start? If you cannot change the ASP application (see answer) then it is not an easy task. I'd not say impossible, but you need to keep in mind that Process.Start opens the Default browser which might be a different one on any computer and even in a different version. Maybe one can do it, but you'd need too much "Magic" so I don't think this is feasible in a stable way.